# Random Python module and creating chances

Tags: python, random

I have a text adventure game with battle system in place already. It is of course turn based, both player and enemy deal damage points (in float). I use `random.uniform()` function to generate attack points for every round.
Zero stands for missing an enemy or player. However since I use floats that chance is pretty slim. I want to create a condition where there would be let's say a chance 1 in 5 that attack points equal 0.00. This condition must be run on every round.

How would I go about it? Is there a module I could use?

note: I think I could use random module (`random.randint(0,5)`) but I was wondering if there is some other way. Thanks!

Comment: Should your attack points be floating point values or integers?

Comment: Both hitpoints and attack points are floats.

Maybe I'm just complicating things... I've tried creating conditions with `random.randint(0,4)` and it works pretty good. But I'm still interested in other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `random.uniform()` reserving 20% of values for 0.00 attack points.

```
hit = random.uniform(0, 10)
if hit <= 2:
    damage = 0.00
else:
    damage = (hit - 2) / 8
```

This is just a stupid example but might help. Or even more simple:

```
hit = random.uniform(0, 10)
if hit >= 8:
    damage = 0.00
else:
    damage = hit / 8
```

Comment: Aaah, I see. Simple mathemathics - should have done this in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest rolling two random numbers: One for the chance to hit and another for the actual damage dealt. You could also combine them with player attributes. Example:

```
if random.uniform(0, 100) < player.chance_to_hit:
    damage = random.uniform(weapon.min_damage, weapon.max_damage)
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up with something like this actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply a chance going from 0 to 1 (float) by a maximum hit damage (int):

```
try:
    chance = 1.0 / random.randint(0, 5)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    chance = 0.0

damage = chance * MAXIMUM_DAMAGE
```

Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

> a **chance 1 in 5** that **attack points** equal **0.00**.

```
if random.randint(1, 5)==1:
    attack_points=0.00
```

|

or if you want to see big true-like numbers:

```
if random.randint(0, 100)<=20:
    attack_points=0.00
```